# Controlling DC motor through bluetooth doesn't work?

Tags: bluetooth, arduino

I'm trying to control DC motor using arduino and through bluetooth.
I used two batteries, one for the arduino and connect it to pin 'Vin' and pin ' GRD '

and the other for the DC motor. When I test it using my smartphone it doesn't work. What is the problem?

This is the code and the connections

```
int motoPin=9;
char value;

void setup() {
    pinMode(motoPin,OUTPUT);
    digitalWrite(motoPin,LOW);
    Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
    value=Serial.read();

    if(value == '1'); digitalWrite(motoPin,HIGH);
    if(value =='0'); digitalWrite(motoPin ,LOW);
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tghmt.png)

Comment: arduino uno ...
i sent a character 1 and 0 ...character 1 make the motor rotate and 0 make it stop !

Comment: value=Serial.read();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot simply connect motor to arduino uno. The board cannot supply enough current to motor and using two batteries with simple interface wont work. We need to put a high current driver (Either a transistor, relay or the most popular motor driver L293D). 
I am sharing a good tutorial for using L293D with arduino.
http://garagelab.com/profiles/blogs/tutorial-l293d-h-bridge-dc-motor-controller-with-arduino

Answer (score 2):

I can see huge mistake in:

```
if(value == '1'); digitalWrite(motoPin,HIGH);
if(value =='0'); digitalWrite(motoPin ,LOW);
```

It is the same as having:

```
digitalWrite(motoPin,HIGH);
digitalWrite(motoPin ,LOW);
```

because of semicolons just after if(...)**;**